# The size of tensor a (296) must match the size of tensor b (298) at non-singleton dimension 2

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I have been running SRGAN to produce super resolution images. I received this error when I tried to add images with different sizes to the training and testing folders. Here's the error:

```
The size of tensor a (296) must match the size of tensor b (298) at non-singleton dimension 2
```

I have done internet researches and found some people suggesting, that the "dimensions in tensors" do not match, so I have to make "adjustments".

As much as that sound like an appropriate piece of advice, I still can't figure out what exactly I can do to "adjust the dimensions of the tensors".

Here's the code that led to the error message.

```
def first_train(epoch):
G.train()

G_loss=0

for batch_idx,(data_lr,data_hr)in enumerate(train_loader):
    if data_lr.size()[0]!=batch_size:
        break
    if cuda:
        data_lr=data_lr.cuda()
        data_hr=data_hr.cuda()
    fake_image=G(data_lr)
    G.zero_grad()

    G_loss=MSE_Loss(fake_image,data_hr)
    G_loss.backward()
    G_optimizer.step()
    G_loss+=G_loss.data

    G_loss/=len(train_loader)

    g_image=fake_image.data.cpu()
    hr_image=data_hr.data.cpu()
    HR_image=torch.cat((hr_image,g_image),0)
    save_image(HR_image,"save_image/epoch_{}.png".format(epoch))
    print("save_image")

    return G_loss

num_epoch=100

for epoch in range(1,num_epoch+1):
    if epoch==1:
        print("trainning start!!")
    g_loss_=first_train(epoch)

    if epoch%1==0:
        torch.save(G.state_dict(),"asset/G_first_epoch{}.pth".format(epoch))
```

"G_loss=MSE_Loss(fake_image,data_hr)" was marked red (indicating that the error derives from this specific code)"

I'd appreciate any advice.

Thanks a million in advance!

Comment: One way to debug is to use print() function and knowing the shape of each of your tensor

Comment: I'm glad you are helping me out, Prakash. I have tried printing out the function. It seems clearer to me now that what I need to do is to resize the images and match them. Thank you very much!